# Can I retrieve an attribute value of ancestor element.. for content: ''; with only pure CSS

Tags: css

i really need help but cannot describe it more accurately because i'm not familiar with english so.. hope to understand :D

just like title, I want to add some strings ( strings from ancestor element's attribute ) using content: ''; property.

I googled it and think ( if i read correctly ) some LESS thing can do this but if there is a way to make this happen without LESS~ or something, want to know.

Thanks~

Comment: I would be surprised if it were possible with LESS.

Comment: Sounds like a job for JavaScript.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you are trying to determine of you can select another element by it's relationship to that DOM element.  Something line parent or sibling?  Unfortunately, I think you can only  explicitly define your CSS selector.  You can easily do this with JavaScript though or jQuery if you want an easier syntax that abstracts out any browser differences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is definitely a job for JavaScript.  LESS is just a CSS Pre-processor and doesn't add any additional functionality in the end.  It will allow you to use variables and other various things to help make it easier to *write* CSS, but will not add functionality to your website.